# background image showing fine except in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8

I am having a real problem here that I just cannot work out. Have built a responsive site, and the pale creme repeated background image set into the container div is not showing on two of my eleven site pages only in IE8 - on the 'home' page and 'info' page - . You see the dark brown background set into the body but not the pale creme in the container. Any ideas?
Have viewed it in lots of other browsers and it is fine. Just not IE8!

Here is the stylesheet code to bring in the background images:

```
body{background:#4f4a39 url(../img/bgdark.png) repeat}

.container{background:#c9c0ae url(../img/bgpale.jpg) repeat}
```

and [the link to the site](http://europewidebuilders.co.uk/dining.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the 'home' and the 'info' page do not have a `<div class='footer'>` inside the `<div class='container'>`. For the other pages, this footer class on the last div has a `clear: both` specified. Which ensures the container div has a height. On the 'info' and 'home' pages, the container div does not have a height. An easy fix would be to add the footer to both pages? If that's not possible. Add 'clear: both' to the css class of the last div inside the container div.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your help with this but sorry you are mistaken.
None of the site pages contain <div class='footer'> as I am using HTML5 which is <footer>. 
I have checked these two pages and the footer is identical, the code is the same. They all have - </footer>
</div><!--/.container-->

Comment: Unfortunatley the issue is not fixed. I have not done anything and It still does not show in IE8. Mmmmm Do you think the problem is in the HTML rather than the CSS styling?

Comment: I'm sorry, I did mean the footer element. Still getting used to this HTML5 business. But you are probably missing a closing tag somewhere, I will have a look. I had reset my IE10 so IE8 mode wasn't on anymore, which made me think you fixed it :)

Comment: Ah I see what the problem is here, HTML5 and IE8 don't really work together. IE8 won't render your HTML5 section and footer tags. have a look at [HTML5Shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/), it provides a way of rendering those HTML5 tags in older browsers. All you'll have to do is include the script.

Comment: You are right!!!! Fantastic!! I used W3 validator and found error. It was a missing closed <article>  tag, on both pages. Thank you so much for your help! You are a star.

Comment: I already have HTML5Shiv script included link in <head>
but thanks for advice

Comment: I should check those things shouldn't I. But yes the missing closing tag has caught me out before :)

Comment: one more thing! The validator also says the following
"Element script must not have attribute charset unless attribute src is also specified.
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

Do you know what this means?


do I simply remove the charset bit?

this is the whole script <br>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider();
  });
</script>

Comment: Well, the charset is useless on a script tag where there is no src specified, it is meant to specify the encoding of the linked file. If there is no src, there is no 'other file', but the script will be embedded inside the HTML page, which means it will automatically have the same encoding as the HTML page. So just remove it to make the validator happy.

Comment: Righto. Will do. The validator also tells me that I should move frameborder="0" scrolling="no"  from my Google maps 'iframe' into my stylesheet. Will the google map still work if I do this? Thank you again for your invaluable help.

Comment: You should be able to get rid of the iframe borders using CSS, and then you can get rid of the frameborder="0" bit. But the scrolling="no" bit should stay there to prevent scroll bar issues in older browsers. Have a look [here](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/2011/03/10/iframe-scrollbars-and-html5/) for some more info on the topic.